# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^{3n} a_n^4$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

> I need to calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^{3n} a_n^4 $$ where $a_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{r}\binom{n+r}{r}\right)^2$ and $e$ is the natural base of logarithm.

I managed to simplify $a_n$ with the following code:

```
Sum[(Binomial[n, r] Binomial[n + r, r])^2, {r, 0, n}]
```

$$a_n= {}_4F_3\left ( -n,-n,n+1,n+1;1,1,1;1 \right )$$ where  ${}_4F_3$ represents the hypergeometric function.

So our limit becomes $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^{3n}{}_4F_3^4\left ( -n,-n,n+1,n+1;1,1,1;1 \right )  $$

I tried a code in Mathematica but could not get an answer:

```
Limit[(E/3)^{3 n}*(HypergeometricPFQ[{-n, -n, n+1, n+1}, {1, 1, 1}, 1])^4, 
 n -> Infinity]
```

Comment: @Domen Thanks for the edit. It is really useful

Comment: Not $3n$ but $3\ n$.

Comment: @Max, do you have any reason to assume/believe that this should converge to a finite number? Glancing at the growth rate (`Table[{n, (E/3)^(3 n)*(HypergeometricPFQ[{-n, -n, n + 1, n + 1}, {1, 1, 1}, 1])^4}, {n, 0, 1000, 100}] // N // Grid`), it feels like this limit is $\infty$.

Comment: @Domen Can you please show how the limit is $\infty$?

Comment: A search of OEIS identifies the sequence as [A005259](https://oeis.org/A005259) "Apery numbers". The asymptotic expansion is given as `(1+Sqrt[2])^(4*n+2)/(2^(9/4)*Pi^(3/2)*n^(3/2))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us leave only the term with `r==n` in the sum. Then

```
r = n; Limit[(Binomial[n, r] Binomial[n + r, r])^8*(E/3)^(3 n),  n -> Infinity]
```

> `\[Infinity]`

Comment: +1 and accepted